# Solr text search is not giving expected results

Tags: search, solr

i have created a document on Solr with field address having following records

1. West 123rd Street
2. West 245th Street

Whenever i search **123rd Street** solr returns both the records. i have also tested using keyword tokenizer but result is same. type of field is solr.textfield.
i have tested with filter query and normal query.

How can i achieve the desired result to show only first record

Comment: If you're using the KeywordTokenizer, neither should give a hit - _if_ you're actually searching against that field, and not against the default search field, which will be `_text_` by default. If the query operator (`q.op`) is `OR`, you'll get any hits that have at least a single match. Use `q.op=AND` to only get entries where every term matches.

Answer (score 0):

you should use phrase query to ahieve the desired result. Use this -

> address:"123rd Street"